ERD for Learning Management System
I've attempted to create an ERD for my Learning Management System project. Here's a quick explanation, admin can manage both teacher and student, teacher can create many classes, students can access the classes, a class contains many learning materials, and one learning material has a quiz:

My examiner highlighted the wrong part of my ERD, and i don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help me to understand what's wrong ?

In principle,  if your professor marks something as wrong,  you should ask him/her first, because it's his/her job to explain it and teach you.
The circled bars correspond to all the cases where you have only one bar.  This is ambiguous,  since it says that there is a "to-one" relationship, but doesn't tell if it's mandatory (double bar) or optional (circle bar).  See details on wikipedia.
The "one time use" comment highlights the fact that your model tells that each class is unique,  i.e.  that teachers can have several classes, that students can participate to several classes,  but each class is exactly one teacher with one student.  I won't do your homework but I can suggest to decompose this table into a class table that describes the class topic and the teacher giving it,  and a participation table that tells which students participate to a class.
The same applies to the quiz.  Here the quizzes are each individual for a single student.  Again,  decompose the table in two,  with a quiz table that describes the quizz,  and a quizz_participation table that tells the performance of a student for a given quizz.
